# Run javascript on website after refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

What I would like to achieve is this:
refresh website
run my javascript script on it (just as if I put it in Chrome console).

Question is: how to achieve it?

I can also use PHP for this (set server on my computer that wil be redirecting to the desired website and execute my javascript program on it).

Some example of functionality I want to achieve:

Go to stackoverflow.com -> click StackExchange (you can see it in the top left corner, it can be accessed by a `querySelector()` in JS) -> refresh stackoverflow.com -> click StackExchange again -> repeat...

Comment: your question is rolling my mind....

Comment: just use the onload event on body.. here's the reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: The problem is when I do something like this:
paste my javascript code to console on the website I want to run JS on and then I refresh the page, I lose this script and it no longer can run, I would have to paste it again and again but I want it to be automatic.

Comment: Setting up onload event doesn't work. I lose script everytime page refreshes (as stated above).

Comment: You can store your code to localStorage and on page load, check whether localStorage is not empty. And if it is not, you can `eval` the code you stored earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the page behind a DOM element click, you can [attach an event handler](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to the element and then in your event handler execute `location.reload()` to [reload the page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp).

Comment: When I reload the page I lose the script and I have to run it again.

Comment: @MindRoller You can add JavaScript on to the page inside `<script></script>` tags that will run when the page loads. Your question includes the jQuery tag, so you might want to put this code inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //When the document has loaded, call the function
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        if(window.location.hash == "#page"){
            console.log("Page reloaded!");
        }else{
            console.log("Page has a new hit!");
        }
    });
```

You can use DOMContentLoaded event listener to solve your problem.

Comment: It does not work because when page refreshes, the script gets lost and I have to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("logdata");

if(value != null) {
    eval(value);
    logdata();
}
```

And try to add `logdata` to `localStorage` from console.
Example - `localStorage.setItem("logdata", "var logdata = function(e) { console.log('data logged.'); }");`

Now when you load the page, `logdata` function will be called and you can have your code executed.

Comment: Does not work aswell, because yeah I can get the item from the local storage but I have to execute it all the time and if page gets refreshed function will stay in the storage but will not execute itself for the next time. It looks like it's impossible to do! Lol!